# Select random records for each users using SQL server in efficient way

Tags: sql-server

I have used the below query to select 5 random records for each shopperId and it is working fine but it is taking time to execute for large number of records (more than 100k records). So is there any way to improve the performance over large amount of data?

```
  SELECT *  FROM (SELECT  
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ShopperID ORDER BY NEWID() DESC )
     AS [Rank] ,
  f.ProductDisplayID,  
  f.ShopperID,  
  f.CreateTS,  
  f.FavoriteID
 FROM  
  #Favorite f )OBJ 

   WHERE OBJ.[Rank]<=5
   order by ShopperID
```

Dummy data:

```
CREATE TABLE #Favorite(
    [FavoriteID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) primary key clustered NOT NULL,
    [ProductDisplayID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [ShopperID] [char](32) NOT NULL,
    [CreateTS] [datetime] NOT NULL
    )
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT #Favorite ON 
GO
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (1, 5209, N'F46AF3C6BDBE4427897A88B043A0DC43', CAST(N'2022-03-16T14:17:28.367' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (2, 2318, N'F46AF3C6BDBE4427897A88B043A0DC43', CAST(N'2022-04-07T17:42:36.030' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (3, 5370, N'F46AF3C6BDBE4427897A88B043A0DC43', CAST(N'2022-04-07T17:42:45.043' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (4, 106, N'F46AF3C6BDBE4427897A88B043A0DC43', CAST(N'2022-04-07T17:42:46.220' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (5, 4014, N'F46AF3C6BDBE4427897A88B043A0DC43', CAST(N'2022-04-07T17:42:47.120' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (6, 4122, N'F46AF3C6BDBE4427897A88B043A0DC43', CAST(N'2022-04-07T17:42:48.060' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (7, 4127, N'F46AF3C6BDBE4427897A88B043A0DC43', CAST(N'2022-04-07T17:42:49.960' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (8, 5372, N'F46AF3C6BDBE4427897A88B043A0DC43', CAST(N'2022-04-07T17:42:50.877' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (9, 5307, N'F46AF3C6BDBE4427897A88B043A0DC43', CAST(N'2022-04-07T17:42:51.630' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (10, 5345, N'F46AF3C6BDBE4427897A88B043A0DC43', CAST(N'2022-04-07T17:42:52.537' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (11, 5358, N'F46AF3C6BDBE4427897A88B043A0DC43', CAST(N'2022-04-07T17:42:53.477' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (12, 3506, N'F46AF3C6BDBE4427897A88B043A0DC43', CAST(N'2022-04-07T17:42:55.600' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (13, 5308, N'F46AF3C6BDBE4427897A88B043A0DC43', CAST(N'2022-04-07T17:42:56.467' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (14, 3994, N'F46AF3C6BDBE4427897A88B043A0DC43', CAST(N'2022-04-07T17:42:57.400' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (15, 5305, N'F46AF3C6BDBE4427897A88B043A0DC43', CAST(N'2022-04-07T17:42:58.290' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (16, 2491, N'F46AF3C6BDBE4427897A88B043A0DC43', CAST(N'2022-04-07T17:42:59.030' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (17, 1271, N'F46AF3C6BDBE4427897A88B043A0DC43', CAST(N'2022-04-07T17:43:00.840' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (18, 1275, N'F46AF3C6BDBE4427897A88B043A0DC43', CAST(N'2022-04-07T17:43:01.887' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (19, 701, N'F46AF3C6BDBE4427897A88B043A0DC43', CAST(N'2022-04-07T17:43:02.683' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (20, 5310, N'F46AF3C6BDBE4427897A88B043A0DC43', CAST(N'2022-04-07T17:43:03.507' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (21, 41, N'F46AF3C6BDBE4427897A88B043A0DC43', CAST(N'2022-04-07T17:43:04.533' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (22, 5314, N'5F1BF5D1679E4724BC02BA2FB91AAB4E', CAST(N'2022-04-07T17:44:51.937' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (23, 253, N'5F1BF5D1679E4724BC02BA2FB91AAB4E', CAST(N'2022-04-07T17:44:52.840' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (24, 312, N'5F1BF5D1679E4724BC02BA2FB91AAB4E', CAST(N'2022-04-07T17:44:53.693' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (25, 313, N'5F1BF5D1679E4724BC02BA2FB91AAB4E', CAST(N'2022-04-07T17:44:55.247' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (26, 3462, N'5F1BF5D1679E4724BC02BA2FB91AAB4E', CAST(N'2022-04-07T17:44:56.067' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (27, 3471, N'5F1BF5D1679E4724BC02BA2FB91AAB4E', CAST(N'2022-04-07T17:44:57.360' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (28, 5265, N'5F1BF5D1679E4724BC02BA2FB91AAB4E', CAST(N'2022-04-07T17:44:58.127' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (29, 5312, N'5F1BF5D1679E4724BC02BA2FB91AAB4E', CAST(N'2022-04-07T17:44:59.180' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (30, 2119, N'5F1BF5D1679E4724BC02BA2FB91AAB4E', CAST(N'2022-04-07T17:45:00.097' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (31, 2913, N'5F1BF5D1679E4724BC02BA2FB91AAB4E', CAST(N'2022-04-07T17:45:00.950' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (32, 4562, N'5F1BF5D1679E4724BC02BA2FB91AAB4E', CAST(N'2022-04-07T17:45:02.370' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (33, 2289, N'5F1BF5D1679E4724BC02BA2FB91AAB4E', CAST(N'2022-04-07T17:45:03.110' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (34, 2116, N'5F1BF5D1679E4724BC02BA2FB91AAB4E', CAST(N'2022-04-07T17:45:04.730' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (35, 3308, N'5F1BF5D1679E4724BC02BA2FB91AAB4E', CAST(N'2022-04-07T17:45:07.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (36, 2103, N'5F1BF5D1679E4724BC02BA2FB91AAB4E', CAST(N'2022-04-07T17:45:08.173' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (37, 2606, N'64E9A938E3384F3DBC8AE747E99A754A', CAST(N'2022-04-07T18:07:59.823' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (38, 5147, N'64E9A938E3384F3DBC8AE747E99A754A', CAST(N'2022-04-07T18:08:00.767' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (39, 2584, N'64E9A938E3384F3DBC8AE747E99A754A', CAST(N'2022-04-07T18:08:01.827' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (40, 975, N'64E9A938E3384F3DBC8AE747E99A754A', CAST(N'2022-04-07T18:08:02.680' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (41, 1814, N'64E9A938E3384F3DBC8AE747E99A754A', CAST(N'2022-04-07T18:08:03.427' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (42, 1066, N'64E9A938E3384F3DBC8AE747E99A754A', CAST(N'2022-04-07T18:08:15.033' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (43, 1789, N'F46AF3C6BDBE4427897A88B043A0DC43', CAST(N'2022-04-26T22:21:11.983' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (44, 29, N'F46AF3C6BDBE4427897A88B043A0DC43', CAST(N'2022-04-26T22:21:12.793' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (45, 4866, N'F46AF3C6BDBE4427897A88B043A0DC43', CAST(N'2022-04-26T22:21:13.693' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (46, 3317, N'F46AF3C6BDBE4427897A88B043A0DC43', CAST(N'2022-04-26T22:21:14.580' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (47, 607, N'F46AF3C6BDBE4427897A88B043A0DC43', CAST(N'2022-04-26T22:21:15.327' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (48, 4933, N'F46AF3C6BDBE4427897A88B043A0DC43', CAST(N'2022-04-26T22:21:17.163' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (49, 4350, N'F46AF3C6BDBE4427897A88B043A0DC43', CAST(N'2022-04-26T22:21:18.133' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (50, 3189, N'F46AF3C6BDBE4427897A88B043A0DC43', CAST(N'2022-04-26T22:21:19.043' AS DateTime))
INSERT #Favorite ([FavoriteID], [ProductDisplayID], [ShopperID], [CreateTS]) VALUES (51, 477, N'F46AF3C6BDBE4427897A88B043A0DC43', CAST(N'2022-04-26T22:21:20.010' AS DateTime))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is recognised that `NEWID()` is relatively slow. You could use the the difference between milliseconds now and the milliseconds part of
`createTS` as a pseudo-random value.

> ```
> SELECT *   FROM (SELECT  
>      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ShopperID 
>        ORDER BY abs(m.m 
>               -datepart(ms,CreateTS)))
>      AS [Rank] ,
>   f.ProductDisplayID,  
>   f.ShopperID,  
>   f.CreateTS,  
>   f.FavoriteID f
>  FROM  
>   #Favorite f ,
>   (select datepart(ms,current_timestamp)
>   m) m)OBJ 
>    
>    WHERE OBJ.[Rank]<=5
>    order by ShopperID
> ```

> ```
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Rank | ProductDisplayID | ShopperID                        | CreateTS                |  f
> ---: | ---------------: | :------------------------------- | :---------------------- | -:
>    1 |              312 | 5F1BF5D1679E4724BC02BA2FB91AAB4E | 2022-04-07 17:44:53.693 | 24
>    2 |             4562 | 5F1BF5D1679E4724BC02BA2FB91AAB4E | 2022-04-07 17:45:02.370 | 32
>    3 |             3471 | 5F1BF5D1679E4724BC02BA2FB91AAB4E | 2022-04-07 17:44:57.360 | 27
>    4 |             2116 | 5F1BF5D1679E4724BC02BA2FB91AAB4E | 2022-04-07 17:45:04.730 | 34
>    5 |              313 | 5F1BF5D1679E4724BC02BA2FB91AAB4E | 2022-04-07 17:44:55.247 | 25
>    1 |             1814 | 64E9A938E3384F3DBC8AE747E99A754A | 2022-04-07 18:08:03.427 | 41
>    2 |              975 | 64E9A938E3384F3DBC8AE747E99A754A | 2022-04-07 18:08:02.680 | 40
>    3 |             5147 | 64E9A938E3384F3DBC8AE747E99A754A | 2022-04-07 18:08:00.767 | 38
>    4 |             2606 | 64E9A938E3384F3DBC8AE747E99A754A | 2022-04-07 18:07:59.823 | 37
>    5 |             2584 | 64E9A938E3384F3DBC8AE747E99A754A | 2022-04-07 18:08:01.827 | 39
>    1 |               41 | F46AF3C6BDBE4427897A88B043A0DC43 | 2022-04-07 17:43:04.533 | 21
>    2 |             5345 | F46AF3C6BDBE4427897A88B043A0DC43 | 2022-04-07 17:42:52.537 | 10
>    3 |             5310 | F46AF3C6BDBE4427897A88B043A0DC43 | 2022-04-07 17:43:03.507 | 20
>    4 |             3317 | F46AF3C6BDBE4427897A88B043A0DC43 | 2022-04-26 22:21:14.580 | 46
>    5 |             5358 | F46AF3C6BDBE4427897A88B043A0DC43 | 2022-04-07 17:42:53.477 | 11
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0c20f56f06ed37a25592cb70720284e8)*

Comment: datepart(ms,CreateTS) is always returning same records, I need to get random records each execution. :(

Comment: Corrected using ms of current_timestamp as a random number generator.

Comment: In this answer same combinations are repeating. First time it is coming as 3308,3462,2119,2289,5265 and the next time 2913,5314,253,2116,312 and repeating. I don't need to repeat any combinations.